# Using tkinter.Canvas stateless-ly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to draw to ttkinter.Canvas like javascript or .NET canvas?

I.E drawline() without storing an object for that line which can be manipulated later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no. HTML5 canvas is just a bitmap canvas that you can "paint" on. Tkinter canvas is vector graphics like SVG, so it keeps a record of each object.

You might want to investigate [PIL's ImageDraw](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm), [aggdraw](http://effbot.org/zone/aggdraw-index.htm), or perhaps [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "storing an object". The canvas gives each thing you draw an id, but you don't have to store it. You can't prevent the canvas from assigning an id to the object but are free to completely ignore it.

What problem are you trying to solve where you perceive this to be an issue?

[edit] To clarify: yes, the interpreter keeps some sort of data for each thing that is drawn. It's not an object in the sense of a Python object though. It's more like a location in memory that describes the thing that was drawn.

Comment: If it stores an id it must store an object somewhere (surely?) if I call 1,000,000 draw calls is memory usage going to increase? Other canvas implementations only manipulate the pixels AFAIK

Comment: Just tested: Memory does increase with every call so we can safely assume it is storing an object for every draw call

Comment: yes, memory will increase a tiny bit with each thing that is added to the canvas, and there is no way around that. The canvas is not a good choice if you are going to draw 1,000,000 objects. You might want to consider some other tool.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this not helpful, or just not the answer you were looking for?

Comment: sorry Bryan, I mean to ask for a method to draw by manipulating pixels without adding an object. If I call draw_line(), a line object will be created that I can move etc after I have drawn it. If I need to draw many objects ontop of each other recursively this uses too much memory. Do you understand?